# USB Device in Virtual Box

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox

I've searched the site and found a common solution to this, however it isn't working for me.

I'm on a MacbookPro running OSX 10.10.5. I'm running the latest VirtualBox release (5.0.something) with Guest Additions and Guest Extensions installed. I have set a USB device (SPI programmer) as a USB filter in my guest OS settings. I have shutdown both the host and guest OS and loaded them back up. After Guest Additions is started on the guest OS (Win 8.1), I then plug in my USB device.

At this point it is not being picked up by Windows 8.1, but instead I can see it in the System Information on my Mac Host OS. I believe the Mac is still taking ownership before the Guest OS.

Can anyone recommend any other steps to remedy this?

Comment: Off-topic for StackOverflow - question belongs on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, right after I posted this my issue was resolved. I switched the USB settings on the Guest OS from USB3.0 -> USB2.0 and my Guest OS was able to finally capture it.

CLosing and accepting my own answer for this.